# Async done() is not working in moch-chai.Unable to access http response

Tags: asynchronous, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I am trying to follow what is provided here - https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/

```
it('fails, as expected', function(done) { // <= Pass in done callback
  chai.request('http://localhost:8080')
  .get('/')
  .end(function(err, res) {
    expect(res).to.have.status(123);
    done();                               // <= Call done to signal callback end
  });
});
```

My code snippet below

```
describe('Scenario: my api test', () => {
  
    let apiResponse;
 
    before('before', function(done)  {
      let chai = require('chai');
      let chaiHttp= require('chai-http')
      chai.use(chaiHttp);
      chai.request(serverurl)
          .get(/endPoint)
          .end(function(err, res) {
            apiResponse = res.body;
            console.log('property1', res.body.metadata.property1)
            console.log('property2', res.body.metadata.property2)
            console.log('property1',apiResponse.metadata.property1)
            console.log('property2', apiResponse.metadata.property2)
            done();
          })   });
  
  
    it('And: I manipulate API REsponse data',() => {
      console.log('printing from next step', apiResponse);
      console.log('printing from next step', apiResponse.metadata.someProperty);
    })
     })
```

Even though I have added call back by **using done()**, logs from my `it` step is executed first. However, after that I am able to see the logs from inside chai block with expected values, followed by the `done is not a function` error.

```
printing from next step undefined
property1  value1
property2  value2
property1  value1
property2  value2

1) Scenario: my api test And: I manipulate API REsponse data:
 Cannot read property 'metadata' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'metadata' of undefined

2) Scenario: my api test "after each" hook:
 done is not a function
 TypeError: done is not a function
```

My goal to store the response in an object and access it in multiple upcoming steps.

Comment: I am also unsure of why  "after each" hook: is displayed in error logs

Comment: In your output you mention your "after each" hook, but your initial code block only includes a before hook. Did you mean your 'before' hook?

Comment: I have defined "before" hook only in my code. But my output shows error logs about "after each" hook which I have not defined.